How do I create a virtual environment in Pydroid without getting "permission denied"?
I used python -m venv Flask but it always returns an error:
/storage/emulated/0 $ python -m venv Flask Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'lib' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Flask/lib64' /storage/emulated/0$


Does the directory /storage/emulated/0/Flask already exist, and if so, did you run this command as a user that has permission to write to that directory?

/storage/emulated/0 is a restricted directory, so you can't run the command there. Try running it in the location where you want to put the project.
